# Microsoft Remote Desktop only works with public ip

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

I'm having a weird issue. When I attempt to RDP into my server using it's local ip(192.168.0.30) my RDP client gets stuck on "Negotiating Credentials". If I use my public/internet ip (port 3389 exposed to the internet) it works fine.

Every client below shows the same behavior (works using WAN IP; fails with LAN IP)

RDP Clients Tested:

- Microsoft Remote Desktop Mac
- Microsoft Remote Desktop Mac Beta
- Remote Desktop Connection (Windows-builtin)
- Microsoft RDP Client Android

Windows Version: 8.1 Pro

Some logs:

```
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): --- BEGIN INTERFACE LIST ---
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): lo0 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): lo0 af=2 (AF_INET)  addr=127.0.0.1 netmask=255.0.0.0
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): lo0 af=30 (AF_INET6)  addr=::1 netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): lo0 af=30 (AF_INET6)  addr=fe80::1%lo0 netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): gif0 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): stf0 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): en0 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): en0 af=30 (AF_INET6)  addr=fe80::1088:3af5:ffd5:d57b%en0 netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): en0 af=2 (AF_INET)  addr=192.168.0.25 netmask=255.255.255.0
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): en1 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): en2 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): bridge0 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): p2p0 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): awdl0 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): awdl0 af=30 (AF_INET6)  addr=fe80::784a:38ff:fee3:da4d%awdl0 netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): utun0 af=18  addr= netmask=
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): utun0 af=30 (AF_INET6)  addr=fe80::b2eb:9d8e:546f:9c59%utun0 netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): --- END INTERFACE LIST ---
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): correlation id: correlation not set or of invalid length
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): Resolved '192.168.0.30' to '192.168.0.30' using NameResolveMethod_DNS(1)
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): Protocol state changed to: ProtocolConnectingNetwork(1)
[2018-Apr-15 10:58:50] RDP (0): Protocol state changed to: ProtocolNegotiatingCredentials(2)
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:11] RDP (0): Exception caught: Exception in file '../../librdpclient/asiosocketendpoint.cpp' at line 400
    User Message : Connection reset by peer
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:11] RDP (0): correlation id: correlation not set or of invalid length
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:11] RDP (0): Protocol state changed to: ProtocolConnectingNetwork(1)
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:11] RDP (0): Resolved '192.168.0.30' to '192.168.0.30' using NameResolveMethod_DNS(1)
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:11] RDP (0): Protocol state changed to: ProtocolNegotiatingCredentials(2)
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:32] RDP (0): Exception caught: Exception in file '../../librdpclient/asiosocketendpoint.cpp' at line 400
    User Message : Connection reset by peer
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:32] RDP (0): Protocol state changed to: ProtocolDisconnecting(7)
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:32] RDP (0): Protocol state changed to: ProtocolDisconnected(8)
[2018-Apr-15 10:59:32] RDP (0): ------ END ACTIVE CONNECTION ------
```

Windows Firewall is off and there's no antivirus installed.

I can't think of any reason why it would fail when using my local ip. I can only assume it's a configuration issue on the router or host computer.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT the server is Windows 8.1

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT So I did some more tests and confirmed a few things. First of all the server and clients are on the same subnet (255.255.255.0). I can also locally telnet into the rdp port (telnet 192.168.0.30 3389).

The logs posted above are from the rdp mac client(app log file). The rdp clients can "connect" to the server, but they get stuck at the "negotiating credentials" step

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT They are both on `192.168.0.x` correct. It only works with the WAN IP, that includes when I'm on the LAN or when I'm external.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Did a traceroute internally using the internal & external ip but didn't see anything interesting, both were just 1 hop. However I did find something interesting. With all my tests I was using wifi, when I connect using ethernet I can RDP using my local ip! but then situation reverses and I can no longer rdp using my external address. It's weird, maybe there's some sort of wifi isolation? There shouldn't be since I can definitely telnet and ping into the computer regardless if I'm on wifi or ethernet. And generally consumer routers only turn on isolation on guest  access points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76077/discussion-between-pimp-juice-it-and-icestorm).